# How to de-duplicate e-mail addresses

Tags: c#, email, email-validation

Is there a way to reliably get a unique e-mail address from one put in from a user?  The problem is services such as GMail allow you to put a period in the address and it's stripped out whereas with other services this is not the case.

GMail:

```
chad.moran@gmail.com
c..hadmoran@gmail.com
c.h.a.d.m.o.r.a.n@gmail.com
```

All of these are the same

Other service:

```
chad.moran@---.com
c..hadmoran@---.com
```

These are unique.

Other than having special logic specifically for GMail is there a better way?

Comment: I have several email accounts that are just forwarding to my gmail account.  Someone who runs their own domain may receive all email that comes to that domain.  So basically no, there isn't any way to be sure that an email address given isn't going to end up in the same mail box as one you already have.

Comment: If your users are deliberately giving you two different email addresses, should you respect their wishes and send to two different addresses?  To me this sounds like some sort of mechanism to ensure "one account per user" which is ultimately going to be flawed for many other reasons too.

Comment: Why, exactly, do you think that you need this? If I give you an altered form of my email address, that's **exactly** the one I expect you to use.

Comment: It's for uniqueness checking for a given form.

Comment: @Chad, chad.moran@gmail.com and c.h.a.d.m.o.r.a.n@gmail.com *are* unique e-mail addresses. They may or may not end up in the same "folder" depending on your GMail settings, but that's just a coincidence. And then you have people with catch-all e-mail addresses (abuse@chadmoran.cx, info@chadmoran.cx etc). So there's no way to algorithmically determine uniqueness-per-user. And "logic specifically for GMail" would be pointless, since GMail is probably the least of your worries (catch-alls etc). :) Also, what @Cody says. You're doing the wrong thing here.

Comment: @Chad Your update to the question makes things even worse. Review the comments and answers given.

Comment: I'm not asking the question to debate what should be and what shouldn't be unique.  I'm not trying to translate users data into what I want, I'm storing and using the address they give me verbatim.

Comment: The problem with your proposed solution (and in fact, *any* proposed solution) is that little clause: **"would not affect *most* users"**. That can be a real problem when you consider the giant audience that is the Internet. It's up to you if your business/enterprise is large or unimportant enough to throw away a percentage of your target audience. That said, I honestly think you're over-engineering this.

Comment: @Cody Throw away?  I'm not throwing away anyone.  The idea is to gate users from entering the form trying to "game" the system we have in place.  The average user would not be affected by the solution only those with similar e-mail addresses with the periods removed.

Comment: Right. "Throw away" meant to be inaccessible or unwelcoming to those users whom your proposed solution inadvertently affects in a negative way. Apparently you think the potential number of people affected is too small to matter. Ultimately that's your call. But there are far better ways of keeping people from gaming the system than placing this type of restrictions on email addresses.

Comment: That's outside the scope of the question.  I only posted my proposed solution to help explain why I wanted to do this but it seems people are more focused on the solution than the question.

Comment: You're not listening. a.b.x@gmail.com and abx@gmail.com are not necessarily the same, and they are absolutely not the same if you replace 'gmail.com' with an arbitrary other domain. The RFCs say nothing about '.' being insignificant.

Comment: I'm not listening?  I never said "." had to be significant.  That's exactly why I gave examples of each case?  Could I possibly not be more clear?  I was fairly certain I already understood the issue.  But thought I would ask to see if there was any other knowledge on the subject.

Comment: Also GMail has a default feature where you can add a "+anything" after your e-mail, and you'll receive it in your mailbox. In your case if you try: `chadmoran+stackoverflow@gmail.com`, you'll receive the e-mail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each email server will have varying rules about what is, and isn't allowed.  You specified you don't want to have specific logic for each client, and for this reason you have to have specific logic.

You could strip out all dots, but other clients might count dotted email addresses as distinct.

I would highly recommend not attempting to try this, as it will be a maintenance nightmare, especially when overnight one of the email services changes their policy.  Also, the benefits of such a system are small, users would just be motivated to register a new email address which is only marginally more difficult than dotting their actual one.

Comment: I think you mean "mail server" where you say "mail client"

Comment: I figured this was the case but I thought I would ask since it didn't seem like there was a similar question that was popular on SO.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible as each individual email service may choose to interpret the "local part" of the email address (the portion before the `@`) it's own way. `chad.moran@gmail.com` and `chadmoran@gmail.com` may route to the same mailbox, but a different provider may route them to separate mailboxes.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part_normalization):

> Interpretation of the local-part of an email address is dependent on the conventions and policies implemented in the mail server. For example, case-sensitivity may distinguish mailboxes differing only in capitalization of characters of the local-part, although this is not very common.